# Display SQL results in table using a for loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I try to display the results from an `sql query` below the results are not within a table and only the table heading is showing. I am wondering if anyone can see where I am going wrong here. Both `slot` and `groupnum` refer to functions which I am returning a value from (not just echoing).

```
if ($numgroups > 0){
    echo '<table>
    <tr><td><b>Time Slot</b></td>
    <td><b>Group</b></td>
    </tr>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numgroups; $i++){
        $q9 = "SELECT `slotid`, `groupid` FROM `schedule` WHERE `groupid` = '".$lecturers_groups [$i]."'";      
        $result9 = mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q9); // Run the query.
        if ($result9) { // If it ran, display the records.
            // Fetch and display the records:
            while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<tr>
                <td>' .slot ($row9['slotid']).'</td>
                <td>' .groupnum($row9['groupid']). '</td>
                </tr>';
            }//While
            echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
            mysqli_free_result ($result9); // Free up the resources.    
            echo "<br><br>";
        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            // Public message:
            echo '<p class="error">The website is currently experiencing problems. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
            // Debugging message:
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br>Query: ' . $q9 . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your  close table tag appears to be inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `close table tag`.
It's inside the `for loop`

Answer (score 0):

Rewire your code like this:

```
<?php
if ($numgroups > 0){
    echo '<table border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Time Slot</th>
                    <th>Group</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numgroups; $i++){
        $q9 = "SELECT `slotid`, `groupid` FROM `schedule` WHERE `groupid` = '".$lecturers_groups [$i]."'";      
        $result9 = mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q9); // Run the query.
        if ($result9) { // If it ran, display the records.
            // Fetch and display the records:
            while ($row9 = mysqli_fetch_array($result9, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<tr>
                <td>' .slot ($row9['slotid']).'</td>
                <td>' .groupnum($row9['groupid']). '</td>
                </tr>';
            }//While

            mysqli_free_result ($result9); // Free up the resources. 
        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            // Public message:
            echo '<p class="error">The website is currently experiencing problems. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
            // Debugging message:
            echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br>Query: ' . $q9 . '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table><br /><br />'; // Close the table.
}
?>
```